# Authentication of Web API and AngularJS SPA app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I have two servers - web and app. The web server (IIS) serves only static files - HTML/CSS/JS. On executing the JS, the client gets the data from the app server (HTTP service using Web API, self hosted with OWIN). I need to bring in authentication so that my data as well as the content is restricted.

I can use SSL, I can pass username / password to the web api, have it authenticated and get back a token. I can pass this token for future web api requests. In my client app javascript (done using AngularJS), I can also maintain info whether the user is authenticated, what roles she has etc. (for user experience). But for security, I need to be able to ensure the html content requested (in the web server) is also having authentication and authorization done. How can I achieve this?

*Should I change my app to make the web server call the app server internally rather than from the client*? I can use MVC controllers or ASP.NET, but since I was using AngularJS, I thought it is not required, and is kind of a duplicate. *Should I ditch pure .html files and move to .cshtml*?

*How is this done in the Angular + .NET world, when you data comes from a different server than your htmls*?

Answer (score 0):

We've been using JSONP with REST type api to do cross domain AJAX calls, but our Angular client code is within .cshtml files in a .NET project. Sounds like the simplest solution is to use the app server internally- I would go with that